# Creating methods inside forEach();

Tags: javascript, methods, foreach

I am trying to create methods for the variable res. The expected result would be `res.add.wood('100')`. This would add 100 to the wood count. `res.get.wheat()` would get the amount of wheat.

Resources are ['wood', 'wheat', 'gold', 'meat'] and actions are ['get', 'set', 'add', 'sub']. I am not looking to define all of them as follows:

```
var resources = ['wood', 'wheat', 'gold', 'meat'];
var actions = ['get', 'set', 'add', 'sub'];

var res;

function res.get.wood() {
  //
}

function res.set.wood() {
  //
}

// 6 more to define.....
```

I am looking to find a way to make it faster.

The following code enables me to use `res.get()`, `res.set()`, `res.add()` and `res.sub()`:

```
var res = ['get', 'set', 'add', 'sub'];

res.forEach(function(arrayElement) {

  res[arrayElement] = function() {
    alert(arrayElement)
  }

});
```

I need another loop, I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
res.forEach(function(arrayElement) {

  ['get', 'set', 'add', 'sub'].forEach(function(arrayInnerElement) {

    res[arrayElement][arrayInnerElement] = function() {
      alert(arrayInnerElement);
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: The API looks weird to me. It would be much simpler to implement `res.add('wood', 10)`, `res.get('gold')`, etc.

Comment: Why not creating class for abstract resource, create correspondent properties in res and use res.wood.add(100), res.wood.get() instead?

Comment: Also, `res.set.wood() {` is a syntax error in JavaScript.

Comment: Why is that? If `.set` and `wood` are methods, why is it an error?

Comment: @ivan When calling a function, `{}` are not used. When declaring a function, you need to either use the `function` keyword.

Comment: Oh I get it, I wasn't calling functions in the first snippet, it was just an example to show how would I have to declare the functions one by one

Comment: FTR, declaring methods on object literals would look like `res.wood.set = function () {};`

Comment: Sorry I realized I forgot `function`!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest something like this:

```js
var resources = { 'wood': 50, 'wheat': 100, 'gold': 0, 'meat': 50 };

var resourceManager = (function(resources) {

  function Resource(amount) {
    this.amount = amount || 0;
  }
  Resource.prototype.get = function() {
    return this.amount;
  };
  Resource.prototype.set = function(amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
  };
  Resource.prototype.add = function(amount) {
    this.amount += amount;
  };
  Resource.prototype.sub = function(amount) {
    this.amount -= amount;
  };

  var o = {};
  Object.keys(resources).forEach(function(resource) {
    o[resource] = new Resource(resources[resource]);
  });
  return o;

}(resources));


var res = resourceManager;
console.log(res.wood.get()); // 50
res.wood.set(10);
console.log(res.wood.get()); // 10
res.wood.add(5);
res.wood.sub(2);
console.log(res.wood.get()); // 13
```

Comment: If I would like to set this.amount for each resource when the object is created, where should I put it inside the code? the constructor?

Comment: I updated the answer. You now have to pass the `resources` object (resource - amount pairs) to the `resourceManager` IIFE to set initial values.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an exiting function to handle all the actions (e.g. executing an API call) and just want a nicer interface, you can create the `res` object using ES5 [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
function resource_action(resource, action, amount) {
  console.log(resource, action, amount);
};

var resources = ['wood', 'wheat', 'gold', 'meat'];
var actions = ['get', 'set', 'add', 'sub'];

var res = resources.reduce(function(res, r) {
  res[r] = actions.reduce(function(act, a) {
    act[a] = function(amount) {
      return resource_action(r, a, amount);
    };
    return act;
  }, {})
  return res;
}, {});

res.gold.add(10);
```

Comment: So basically you're creating all the necessary methods and run a big function to handle the parameters, right?

Comment: yes.. assuming you would dispatch the actions as API calls to the server, not actually adding or substracting on the client, so you don't need individual action implementations

Answer (score 0):

Just set the prototype object to your new objects and define it there.

```
function Item () {
    this.get = function () {alert("got me");}
    this.set = function () {}
    this.add = function () {}
    this.sub = function () {}
  }


  function Wood () {

  }

  Wood.prototype = new Item ();
```

then all you have to do is:

```
 var newWoodItem = new Wood();
```

and if you need to override one of the methods.

```
 function Wood () {
    this.get = function () {alert("i am the new method.");}
 }
```

Comment: I think it'd be nicer if `Item` were an object literal.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it "jQuery style", with functions that work like `$(el).css('color','red')` like this:

```js
// Create a Stock Object
var res = new Stock();

// Play with it
console.log( res.get('wood')     );  // 0
console.log( res.set('wood', 10) );  // 10
console.log( res.get('wood')     );  // 10
console.log( res.add('wood', 5)  );  // 15
console.log( res.sub('foo', 5)   );  // false (undefined resource)


function Stock() {
    var resource_types = ['wood', 'wheat', 'gold', 'meat'],
        resources = {};

    init();

    function init() {
        for(var i=0; i<resource_types.length; i++) {
            resources[ resource_types[i] ] = 0;
        }
    }

    function add(resource, value) {
        if(is_resource(resource)) {
            resources[ resource ] += parseFloat(value);
            return resources[ resource ];
        }
        return false;
    }

    function sub(resource, value) {
        if(is_resource(resource) && parseFloat(value) <= resources[ resource ]) {
            resources[ resource ] -= parseFloat(value);
            return resources[ resource ];
        }
        return false;
    }

    function set(resource, value) {
        if(is_resource(resource)) {
            resources[ resource ] = parseFloat(value);
            return resources[ resource ];
        }
        return false;
    }

    function get(resource) {
        if(is_resource(resource)) {
            return resources[ resource ];
        }
        return false;
    }

    function is_resource(str) {
        return resource_types.indexOf(str) > -1;
    }

    return {
        add: add,
        sub: sub,
        set: set,
        get: get
    };
}
```